Matplotlib: ImportError
ImportError         
Cell In[5], line 5
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
      6 import statsmodels.api as sm

File c:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py:272
    267         if parse_version(module.__version__) < parse_version(minver):
    268             raise ImportError(f\"Matplotlib requires {modname}>={minver}; \"
    269                               f\"you have {module.__version__}\")
--> 272 _check_versions()
    275 # The decorator ensures this always returns the same handler (and it is only
    276 # attached once).
    277 @functools.cache
    278 def _ensure_handler():

File c:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py:266, in _check_versions()
    257 from . import ft2font
    259 for modname, minver in [
    260         (\"cycler\", \"0.10\"),
    261         (\"dateutil\", \"2.7\"),
   (...)
    264         (\"pyparsing\", \"2.3.1\"),
    265 ]:
--> 266     module = importlib.import_module(modname)
    267     if parse_version(module.__version__) < parse_version(minver):
    268         raise ImportError(f\"Matplotlib requires {modname}>={minver}; \"
    269                           f\"you have {module.__version__}\")

File c:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py:90, in import_module(name, package)
     88             break
     89         level += 1
---> 90 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File c:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\kiwisolver\\__init__.py:8
      1 # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2 # Copyright (c) 2013-2022, Nucleic Development Team.
      3 #
   (...)
      6 # The full license is in the file LICENSE, distributed with this software.
      7 # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 8 from ._cext import (
      9     Constraint,
     10     Expression,
     11     Solver,
     12     Term,
     13     Variable,
     14     __kiwi_version__,
     15     __version__,
     16     strength,
     17 )
     18 from .exceptions import (
     19     BadRequiredStrength,
     20     DuplicateConstraint,
   (...)
     24     UnsatisfiableConstraint,
     25 )
     27 __all__ = [
     28     \"BadRequiredStrength\",
     29     \"DuplicateConstraint\",
   (...)
     41     \"__kiwi_version__\",
     42 ]

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext:
I reinstalled matplotlib, but nothing changed. Installed the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++. No changes.
I also tried to uninstall and reinstall matplotlib. Everything proceeds without errors. But there is still a problem with importing the module.
I also tried installing an earlier version of matlotlib 3.8.1, but it did not help.
